# using multiple id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made little jquery script for checking if input box value bigger than 5 .but I have 2  tag with an id and only one of them works.

```
<div id="register">
    <form id="register">
<input id="first" type="text" /> <a id="first" ></a> <br />
    <input id="second" type="text" /> <a id="second" ></a>

</form>
```

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val().length<5)
   {
  $('a.first').text("Please fill"); 
   }
if($(this).val().length<5){
     $('a.second').text("Please fill"); 
   }
});
```

But it shows only first `<a id="first"></a>` tag. Second tag not visible

Comment: You should never have two IDs with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your `<a>`'s to use classes:

```
<div id="register">
    <form id="register">
       <input id="first" type="text" /> <a class="first" ></a> <br />
       <input id="second" type="text" /> <a class="second" ></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

The jQuery selectors you're using:

```
$('a.first')
$('a.second')
```

Are looking for an `<a>` with a class.  If you were trying to look for an `<a>` with an id, they would need to be as follows:

```
$('a#first')
$('a#second')
```

Answer (score 1):

change the ID of register , its not correct to have two identical ID's in the same page , 
after that everything should be working fine

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with not having duplicate id's. Easier to keep track of, and cleaner code. My two cents :), after having to refactor a chunk of code at work recently that had duplicate id's that failed to work in IE. Lesson learned!